# Using same form for insert and edit

Tags: forms, mongodb, insert, meteor, edit

How can I use the same form for inserting and editing a document in Meteor.

For insert I use empty form without variable:

```
<template name="frmOrganization">
   // no doc variable
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     ...
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
```

And for update I use form with variable:

```
<template name="frmOrganization">
   {{#with organization}} // doc variable
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     ...
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" value="{{Name}}">
```

Comment: Use the second for both update and insert. Undefined {{Name}} just evaluates to empty string.

Answer (score 2):

(Using Meteor 0.9.3 + Iron-Router)

I had the same issue and the workaround I used was as follows (seems to be more of a hack but I get to avoid having multiple forms)

```
<template name="frmOrganization">
// no doc variable
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  ...
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" value={{name}}>
  {{#if name}}
    <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
  {{else}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
  {{/if}}
  ...
```

In my router.js file

```
this.route('frmOrganization', {
  path: '/organisation/:_id/edit',
  data: function() { return Organisation.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

All seems pretty standard, but then for my Add link, I use:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'frmOrganization' _id=new}}">Add</a>
```

Which will create he following link:

```
/organisation/null/edit
```

The null page gives you your Add page and an ID would give you your edit page.

-- Meteor Noob

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use an [upsert](http://docs.meteor.com/#upsert) with the _id of the organization document as the first argument. If nothing is found in the collection when you try to upsert, then it will insert the data into a new document (second argument).

However, there are some packages which can make this task much easier:

[autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/package/autoform), simple-schema and collection2

*(I would link to the others but lack the reputation)*

Firstly define a schema and apply it to the collection as follows:

```
Pages = new Meteor.Collection('pages');

PagesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Title',
    max: 100
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Body',
    max: 1000
  }
});

Pages.attachSchema(PagesSchema);
```

Then it's possible to simply switch these two templates for an insert or update:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Pages" id="page-form" type="insert"}}

{{> quickForm collection="Pages" doc=page id="page-form" type="update"}}
```

(With 'page' being the document itself available in the template)

These handlebars helpers will produce the entire form, and you can even validate with them.

Comment: Ok, I know how to do it with two forms, one for insert and one for edit, but I don't want to create 2 or 3 forms (for delete also) for each document type.

Comment: I tried also with autoform, with using "this" as document handle, but it doesn't work properly. And update hook is poorly documented and it doesn't update the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Say that you have a `create` form at path `/my-form`. This is fairly straightforward. It creates a new document in your database with an :_id of, say, XYZ123.

Now you want an edit form.

You create a link that goes to `/my-form/XYZ123`

You've created a path with the document :_id as a parameter.

You then set your route to read the :_id parameter of your path as data. (Look at the Discover Meteor book for an example)

Now add code to your existing form that will take that :_id from the path, do a lookup for the document, and pre-populate the values in the form with the values it finds from the database based off of that :_id.

And change the submit button to do an update instead of insert.

As for delete, that's simple. No extra form needed. On the edit form just create a big red delete button that will delete the document with that :_id.

Write your JS so that if there is a parameter in the path, make the delete button visible and turn the submit button from insert into update.